# Why LineNumberTable is not enabled default in ProGuard configuration in Android?

Tags: android, proguard

It is very very hard to use the crash reports without knowing the line numbers. Also you cannot debug the code without line numbers as well.

Is there a specific reason to disable the line numbers when using ProGuard?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, ProGuard strives for the leanest possible application. It removes all elements from your code that are not strictly necessary for running it. You can preserve line numbers if you expect you'll need them, at the price of a very small increase in application size.

Comment: Is there a way to easily and properly debug the app without line numbers? If there is I won't keep them.

Comment: It's possible, but it's a lot harder, since the stack traces become very ambiguous without line numbers.

Comment: Ok then it is logical to add line numbers. But let's think a developer that just add in app billing. In the documentation it recommends to enable proguard. A beginner developer who do not proguard at all finds how to enable it and do it and then upload his app to the store. And later in the error logs,  he won't see the lone numbers and he cannot debug at all. I think the developers should be informed in the proguard documentation.

Comment: What do you think about informing developers about line numbers on the front page of the ProGuard tutorial on Android Developers web site? A beginner Android developer who just enable ProGuard cannot debug the app at all and it is very frustrating.

Comment: Google describes how to map the stacktrace here http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding